# How to use environment variable(string) in a .conf file

Tags: bash, configuration, environment-variables

I have a .conf file that has a label and variable that I'm trying to move to a .env file. How can I accomplish this?

This is what I have in my .conf file

```
[[inputs.snmp]] #Label
    agents = ["1.1.1.1:111","2.2.2.2:111","2.3.3.3:111"] #Variable
    version = 2 #Variable
```

I'm trying to have something like this in the .env file

```
VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE='[[inputs.snmp]]\n    agents= ["1.1.1.1:111","2.2.2.2:111","2.3.3.3:111"]\n    version=2'
```

I was hoping I could use `$VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE` in my .conf file instead of `[[inputs.snmp]]agents = ["1.1.1.1:111","2.2.2.2:111","2.3.3.3:111"]`
but I keep getting this error `Error parsing data: line 7: invalid TOML syntax`  for `$VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE` (Im not sure if I'm getting this error because I have the syntax wrong in my .env file or I'm declaring $VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE incorrectly in my .conf file)

Am I doing it correctly (or is it even possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish)?

(Note: I'm trying to accomplish this so I can simply use `$VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE` instead of hard coding things in the .conf file)

Comment: You better show the line of code which generates the error. BTW, this is not an error message issued by bash itself.

Comment: @user1934428 That line 7 is the line above the error that I posted. Thats what I get.

Comment: This is just a variable assignment. It can not produce this error. See [here](https://www.4shared.com/s/ffGQPxEi3ea).

Comment: @user1934428 if you are asking how I'm using the variable assignment in my .env file then I'm simply using $VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE (which happens to be on line 7 too - sorry for the confusion)

Comment: I don't see in your post, how you would use this. It does not make sense to discuss an error you get, if we don't see the code which produces it.

Comment: please update the question with the actual contents of the .conf file where the variable reference is being made; I'm in agreement with Armali's answer ... probably an issue with the program that's parsing the .conf file ... hard to say without knowing **what** is using the .conf file and **what** exactly is in the .conf file

Comment: @user1934428 Im only using $VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE as it itself is a string that is suppose to be a label and variable in the conf. file. That is why I asked how I can convert it to a string - The one I have clearly does not work that is why I asked

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your explanation. You really should put this statement into your question (and maybe the one or two statements before). There is no _conversion to string_ in bash. All scalar variables are of type String. bash doesn't really have a type system.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to use VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE in the .conf file

If the .conf file parsing program doesn't support variable substitution, there's no way around *modifying the .conf file*, but this can be automated:

```
sed -i "s/\<VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE\>/$VAR_FOR_CONF_FILE/" my.conf
```